# Toobar setup in PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to setup toolbar in preference activity using below code . it does shows Toolbar but it overlays with preferences list. 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smPMh.jpg)  a screenshot link from my app
I m doing this bcz i m changing the style theme at runtime. I have implemented it in other activities but i want it also for PreferenceActivity.

**SettingsActivity**

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        getDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarsettings));
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainPrefernceFragment()).commit();

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {


        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }






    public static class MainPrefernceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID)
    {
        getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume()
    {
        super.onPostResume();
        getDelegate().onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        getDelegate().onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        getDelegate().onDestroy();
    }

    private void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar)
    {
        getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate()
    {
        if (mDelegate == null)
        {
            mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
        }
        return mDelegate;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarsettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will solve your problem:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarsettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the java code:

```
 package com.matingdz.myapplication;

import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;


    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        getDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarsettings));
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainPrefernceFragment()).commit();

        String[] x = new String[]{"AAA","BBB","CCC"};
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> test = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,x);
        lv.setAdapter(test);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {


        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


    public static class MainPrefernceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID)
    {
        getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume()
    {
        super.onPostResume();
        getDelegate().onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        getDelegate().onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        getDelegate().onDestroy();
    }

    private void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar)
    {
        getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate()
    {
        if (mDelegate == null)
        {
            mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
        }
        return mDelegate;
    }

}
```

Comment: its crashes like Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: @Naveed sorry for that, I have edited my answer. Check it again.

Comment: Did you implemented preferenceActivity r its a simple list view

Comment: Its working with your code but when i add addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); 
Its not working

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the final solution
**activity_settings.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nanosoft.icstudio.SettingsActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarsettings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>



    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Some changes in java class
>   **SettingsActivity**

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MainPrefernceFragment()).commit();
```